# Which HTTP Method is used to send SOAP messages?

Tags: web-services, http, servlets, soap

Which HTTP Method is used to send SOAP messages?

I guess, if you are working at the servlet level,you could define the HTTP method(would there still be restrictions?).

But if all that is hidden, and I'm using a simple JAX WS webservice, which HTTP method would(should??) the request and response messages have?

Answer (score 1):

I think JAX-WS and most other implementations use post for transmitting requests

you can verify it by capturing the request in TCP IP monitor